# ¿Como desarrollar un lenguaje de programación?

Tags: programación-bajo-nivel

Actualmente estoy interesado en desarrollar un lenguaje de programación para un proyecto sencillo que tengo en mente.

Mi pregunta es ¿Por dónde comienzo? ¿Qué debo aprender al respecto? ¿Existe algún libro que me ayude?

He buscado por la web y realmente no encuentro nada que me satisfaga, por ahora se que tengo que desarrollar un compilador, comprendo que es algo loco, pero por algo se empieza.

Comment: Hola J. Daza. Lastimosamente, este tipo de preguntas tan abiertas no se pueden realizar en el sitio. Sin embargo, puedes acceder al [salón de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde esas preguntas son bienvenidas puesto que el chat es más informal y las personas cuentan sus opiniones sobre diversos temas. Solo haz click en el enlace de este comentario.

Comment: Buenas, JDaza, secundo lo que dice @toledano. Sin embargo, para participar en el chat tienes que tener 20 de reputacion... un saludo

Comment: ya habras notado que esta pregunta tal como esta no encaja en el sitio puede mirar [ask] por si en un futuro le hace falta. Ahora yo le recomendaria mirar el libro del dragon "purpura" es la "nueva" edicion -> https://www.amazon.es/dp/9702611334/ref=pd_cp_14_1/259-9351669-8808426?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=92FQGZNZJQ470XWGSZX8 despues puede mirar o buscar repositorios en github sobre compiladores, existen muchos compiladores creados en varios lenguajes que le pueden ayudar como base ect suerte. Saludos